# How to run a cgi script independently for concurrent connections

Tags: perl, apache

I'm just starting out with web development.
For apache server 2.4, with mpm_prefork and cgi enabled.

As a cgi application, I've the following perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
local $| = 1;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

$r = int(rand(1000000));
for (my $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
       print "$i $r\n";
       sleep(2);
}
```

If I run this cgi script in two browser tabs (localhost/cgi-bin/sleep.pl), then the second one starts only after the first one is complete.

I'd like to able to run these concurrently. Is there an apache configuration setting for this or do I have to fork within the perl script itself?

thanks,

Comment: I am skeptical that is not already concurrent.

Comment: I agree with codnodder... I'm inclined to think that your browser is delaying the second call until the first one is done, since you are requesting the same resource.  Maybe try from a different browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox) instead of just a separate tab.

Comment: Yes, Tim you're right. I tried with different browsers and I was able to 'get' the resource concurrently.
thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined to think that your browser is delaying the second call until the first one is done, since you are requesting the same resource. Maybe try from a different browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox) instead of just a separate tab. – Tim A